# Access a dynamically created control through javascript - ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, jquery, jquery-ui, dynamic

I've a JavaScript function in my page through which i make some elements in the page as 'JQuery UI droppable'.

```
function setDroppableTargets()
{
$(.cssDockZone).droppable();
}
```

But the elements with the class cssDockZone is created dynamically upon user interaction. So in the code behind i create the control first and finally at the end i register a scriptblock which calls setDroppableTargets().

```
//set droppable targets
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "setDroppableTargets", "setDroppableTargets()", true);
```

But the javascript function is invoked before the controls are created eventhough i register the script at the end (after creating the controls) and i cross checked it by getting the elements with class name '.cssDockZone' and i getting it as 0.

```
$(.cssDockZone).length
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `"$(setDroppableTargets);"` for your script, instead of `"setDroppableTargets()"`, that work?

Comment: Try this: $(window).bind("load", setDroppableTargets)

Comment: Thank you Nick. I found out the issue. I messed up some code in the server side. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using '.' before the css class name while assigning them to the control. Silly. Removing the '.' fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(function(){
          var _length= $(.cssDockZone).length;
});
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? I dont understand. My problem is that the client script is called before the controls are created.

Comment: this way "var _length= $(.cssDockZone).length;"  part will be run after client controls created and in DOM and DOM is ready.